# Haskell RPC framework in production

Tags: haskell, rpc

I really think Haskell is a awesome programming language, but it seems that Haskell lacks the handy and mature tools can be used in production.
Does Haskell have a mature, stable and convenient RPC framework to use like Finagle in Scala? Has any one use Haskell in production and how do they handle the communication between different ends? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. There is https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/HaXR. If JSON is more your thing then there's also http://hackage.haskell.org/package/json-rpc-server, but that's only for the server side (the same guy is also doing a client library but it's not as mature)

Having said that: RPC should always be the last resort because it's always bad for reliability and performance (this is general programming advice, not specific to Haskell)